# Quantlib - giving a strange error

Tags: python, yield, quantlib

I am using Quantlib to bootstrap a curve and then get the discounting rate.

In general the usual steps work fine.

However, for the data given below, it throws a strange error.

**Code:**

```
def create_ois_swaps(self, ois_swap_rates, helpers=None):
    ''' Creates a OIS rate helper from incoming OIS rates
        Input:
        ois_swap_rates: list of tuples comprising of (start_date, end_date, rate, label)
    '''
    if self.helpers is None:
        self.helpers = [
            DatedOISRateHelper(start_date, end_date, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)), self.ff_local)
            for start_date, end_date, rate in [tuple((fixed_bond.pydate_to_qldate(sd),
                                                      fixed_bond.pydate_to_qldate(ed),
                                                      rate)) for sd, ed, rate, label
                                               in ois_swap_rates if label not in ['ONTN', 'TN']]]
    else:
        self.helpers += [DatedOISRateHelper(start_date,
                                            end_date,
                                            QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)), self.ff_local)
                         for start_date, end_date, rate in [tuple((fixed_bond.pydate_to_qldate(sd),
                                                                   fixed_bond.pydate_to_qldate(ed),
                                                                   rate)) for sd, ed, rate, label
                                                            in ois_swap_rates if label not in ['ONTN', 'TN']]]
    # for start_date, end_date, rate in ois_swap_rates]
    self.ois_curve_c = PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, self.calendar, self.helpers, Actual365Fixed())
    self.ois_curve_c.enableExtrapolation()

def bootstrap_usd_ois_3M_curve(self,
                               usd_3M_swap_rates,
                               discountCurve,
                               bootStrapMethod=BootStrapMethod.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount):

    discount_curve = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
    discount_curve.linkTo(discountCurve)
    self.helpers += [SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                                    Period(int(label[:-1]), Years),
                                    TARGET(),
                                    Semiannual,
                                    Unadjusted,
                                    Thirty360(Thirty360.BondBasis),
                                    Euribor3M(),
                                    QuoteHandle(),
                                    Period(0, Days),
                                    discount_curve)
                     for sd, ed, rate, label in usd_3M_swap_rates if label not in ['ONTN', 'TN']]
    # for rate, tenor in usd_3M_swap_rates]

    if bootStrapMethod == BootStrapMethod.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount:
        self.usd_3M_c = PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, TARGET(), self.helpers, Actual365Fixed())
    elif bootStrapMethod == BootStrapMethod.PiecewiseFlatForward:
        self.usd_3M_c = PiecewiseFlatForward(0, TARGET(), self.helpers, Actual365Fixed())

    # Also, we enable extrapolation beyond the maturity of the last helper; that is mostly
    # for convenience as we retrieve rates to plot the curve near its far end.
    self.usd_3M_c.enableExtrapolation()
```

in my main code, I call the above 2 functions as:-

## create the OIS curve

`usd_ois.create_ois_swaps(ois_rate_ql)`

## bootstrap the curve

`usd_ois.bootstrap_usd_ois_3M_curve(usd_3M_swap_rates=libor_rate_ql,
discountCurve=usd_ois.ois_curve_c,                                          bootStrapMethod=BootStrapMethod.PiecewiseFlatForward)`

**Dates:**

> Curve valuation date: 2017.01.02

for discounting_Rate:-

> start_date: 2017.01.02 
>   end_date: 2018.01.01
>   dayCount: ACT/360

**Error message:**

> return _QuantLib.YieldTermStructure_forwardRate(self, *args)
>   RuntimeError: negative time (-0.00273973) given`

**Curve object**

> [curve object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVewU.jpg)
>   **Data used:**
>   [libor and OIS rates used for bootstrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GMxk.jpg)

**State of curve object**

[state of curve object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQGqU.jpg)

Notice I have a 
1) discounting OIS curve and a 
2) forward 3M curve

Valuation date is Jan 2nd , 2017

The call I am making is on the discounting curve as follows:-
   `ois_curve.ois_curve_c.forwardRate(pydate_to_qldate(start_date),
                                             pydate_to_qldate(end_date),
                                             daycount, Simple).rate() * 100`

where start_Date = 2nd Jan, 2017
   end_date = 2nd Jan, 2018

I am running the same code over a range of dates. Most of the dates- its successful, but few of the dates- it strangely throws this error

Comment: You're probably asking for a rate at a date before the start of the curve. What is your evaluation date? How did you build the curve?

Comment: I have added some data and screenshots. Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: What do you get if you call `curve.referenceDate()`?

Comment: Hi Luigi, please see the section "State of Curve object" that I have added to the above section

Comment: What do you get if you call `ois_curve.ois_curve_c.referenceDate()`?

Comment: I get Jan 3rd, 2017. This is strange! How does it increment by a day when I pass in valuationDate= Jan 2nd on creation?

Comment: I suspect that the valuation date is a holiday for the calendar the curve is using, so it moves the reference date to the next business day.

Comment: Makes sense. 2nd jan 2017 is a public holiday. So internally it has moved to next business day. The error message is very confusing. Also , I don’t think it should move forward, should just throw an error. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I'm summarizing here the comments above.  The evaluation date (January 2nd, 2017) is a holiday for the calendar used by the curve; therefore, the curve moves its reference date to the next business day. At that point, January 2nd is in the past as far as the curve is concerned and asking for a rate on that date results in an error.

I agree that, at least, the error should be made more readable.  I'm not sure that setting the evaluation date to a holiday should necessarily invalidate the curve.  Throwing an error is probably not feasible; we might have different curves using different calendars, and setting the evaluation date to a holiday for one of those should be ok as long as we only use the valid curves.